# Visualizing a Probability Space in Wolfram w/Two Events?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

For two events say $A$ and $B$, and supposing we have the data: $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$, is there a way to generate something like a "probability venn diagram" from this information? The following information online is kind of what I mean:

> [image]

If there are other ways of visualizing this in Wolfram then I would be interested in those approaches as well.

Comment: Probably the source of the picture: https://oscarbonilla.com/2009/05/visualizing-bayes-theorem/    ;)

Answer (score 6):

Usually, this works:

Generating random probabilities:

```
SeedRandom[12];
(
 Label["Beginning"];
 PA = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
 PB = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
 PAcondB = RandomReal[{0, 1}];
 PAandB = PAcondB PB;
 PBcondA = PAandB/PA;
 If[PB + PA - PAandB > 1. || PBcondA > 1., Goto["Beginning"];];
 )
```

Determining disks for the events A and B and a region of area 1 that contains both:

```
rA = Sqrt[PA/Pi];
rB = Sqrt[PB/Pi];
ΩA[x_] := Disk[{-x/2, 0}, rA];
ΩB[x_] := Disk[{x/2, 0}, rB];
F[x_] := Area[RegionIntersection[ΩA[x], ΩB[x]]];
d = x /. FindRoot[F[x] == PAandB, {x, Max[rA, rB] - Min[rA, rB], 0.999999 (rA + rB)}];

union = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   RegionUnion[ΩA[d], ΩB[d]], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {1 -> 0.01}
];
Ω = TransformedRegion[union, {x, y} \[Function] 1/Sqrt[Area[union]] {x, y}];
Graphics[{
  White, EdgeForm[Black], Ω,
  Opacity[0.5],
  Blue, ΩA[d],
  Red, ΩB[d]
  }]
```

[image]

The shape for the overall probability space is not overly beautiful. Maybe anybody else finds a way to round it off nicely.

Comment: For the shape for the overall probability space you can use `BoundingRegion[\[CapitalOmega], "FastEllipse"]` (+1  of course)

Answer (score 2):

Given any three of the five magnitudes $P(A), P(B), P(A\cap B), P(A|B), P(B|A)$, the remaining two are determined thru well known relations. We generate the first three randomly.

```
SeedRandom[777]
{pa, pb} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2]
```

> {0.183545, 0.903397}

```
pab = RandomReal[{0, Min[pa, pb]}]
```

> 0.138116

```
{pbconda, pacondb} = pab/{pa, pb}
```

> {0.752495, 0.152886}

The radii of the two circles that represent the events $A$ and $B$:

```
{ra, rb} = Sqrt[{pa, pb} / Pi]
```

> {0.241711, 0.536246}

To find how far apart the two circles should be, we can use the function `A[R, r, d]` from [Eric Weisstein - "Circle-Circle Intersection" from MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) for the area of the asymmetric lens in the intersection of two circles with radii `R` and `r` and centered at `{0, 0}` and `{d, 0}`, respectively.

```
ClearAll[A]
A[R_, r_, d_] :=  r^2 ArcCos[(d^2 + r^2 - R^2)/(2 d r)] + 
  R^2 ArcCos[(d^2 + R^2 - r^2)/(2 d R)] - 
  Sqrt[(-d + r + R) (d + r - R) (d - r + R) (d + r + R)]/2

xd = x /. FindRoot[A[ra, rb, x] - pab, {x, (ra + rb)/2}]
```

> 0.421014

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], FaceForm[Opacity[.5]], Red, 
  Disk[{0, 0}, ra], Blue,  Disk[{xd, 0}, rb], FaceForm[Opacity[0]], 
  Disk[{xd/2, 0}, 1/(pa + pb - pab)], 
  Text[Style["A", 16, Black], Offset[{-5, 0}, {-ra, 0}], Right], 
  Text[Style["B", 16, Black], Offset[{5, 0}, {xd + rb, 0}], Left],
  Text[Style["A⋂B", 16, Black], 
   Offset[{-20, 0}, {xd/2, 0}], Center]}]
```

[image]

Verify that the ratios of the intersection to the two disk areas match the given conditional probabilities:

```
Chop[Norm[
  Area[RegionIntersection[Disk[{0, 0}, ra],  Disk[{xd, 0}, rb]]] /
     {Area[Disk[{0, 0}, ra]], Area[  Disk[{xd, 0}, rb]]} -
   {pbconda, pacondb}], 10^-9]
```

> 0